# How to use Database by opening File to send and receive data from Server to Client?

Tags: f#, f#-data, f#-3.0, websharper

I want to receive data (simply as a string) from the client-web side to update the database, but it's a bit lock for me now, so first write the data to a file in the drive with using `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"my-file.txt")`

---

I got that error

```
error FS9001: Method name not found in JavaScript compilation: (receive : System.Object -> unit)
```

---

Can you tell me where I did wrong and fix it?

---

- [Remoting.fs](https://gist.github.com/tungandcun/3daea9b22cab5bfab7a9475bf5b447c2)
- [Client.fs](https://gist.github.com/tungandcun/10a115c29a59799a3d632c70b3f968d1)
- [Main.fs](https://gist.github.com/tungandcun/97173c94ff5faec6335ff7c9a91f8c9a)

Answer (score 2):

WebSharper's client side can call methods that are themselves in `[<JavaScript>]` scope or marked `[<Remote>]` for remote calls. The error message is not mentioning the second option, but that is what you need here (same as the sample function `DoSomething` has it too).

You will also need to make the remote function to not send over an `obj` but a `string`. Remote function arguments are deserialized based on type information and cannot be `obj`. For example in client code, use `Server.receive rvInput.Value`. (`rvInput` is a reactive variable for which `.Value` contains current value)

Note that if you want to return a value to the server, the remote function must be an `async`. Here, just for logging, returning `unit` works too, but then you have no way on the server to determine if the logging was successful. By returning an `async<unit>`, you can catch errors in the client code if you want to guard against connection or server errors. Again, the sample code in the template gives some guidance.

Comment: I'm making everything as simple as possible as you can see in the following code [Remoting](https://gist.github.com/tungandcun/09ea271409f53f90a1f74d712010bdcb)  but I still get that error FS9001: Type not found in JavaScript compilation: SampleWebsite.receive

Comment: Your `module receive` is not marked with `[<JavaScript>]`

Answer (score 2):

(Cross posting from http://forums.websharper.com/topic/84579)

Here is what your server-side function should look like:

```fs
[<Remote>]
let Receive (input: string) =      
    async {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:/myDatabase.txt", "Server received data: " + input)
    }
```

and to call it from `Client.fs`, you need:

```
...
        button [
            on.click (fun _ _ ->
                async {
                    do! Server.Receive rvInput.Value
                } |> Async.Start
            )
        ] [text "Receive"]
...
```